# Pandas merge tables with two columns in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working on two big data bases:

**dataM**:
[image]

**dataD**
[image]

I want to `join` the two data frames by **County** and **State** and **Year**, but the dataM has to retain all of the columns, and only get de Deprivation Index Percent of the dataD. Also, I want to `drop` the rows where counties does not exist on one or the another. For instance, on dataM we have AK and its counties, but on dataD there is not AK, so I want to `drop` all those rows on dataM. In the same way, if the counties and states exist in both, I want to assign the Deprivation Index Percent to all the rows with that county in that state. I tried everyting, buy I can't make it work.

I tried this in many forms:

```
dataM = pd.merge(dataM, dataD, how='right', left_on=['County', 'State'], right_on=['County', 'State'])
```

and by filtering Baldwin county which is on both data frames, I got this:

[image]

I don't understand why I am getting NaN if the county and state exist in both data frames. Please help me.

Comment: problem seems to be you using right join , use left join i.e how='left' i.e dataM = pd.merge(dataM, dataD, how='left', on=['County', 'State'])

Comment: It shows the correct data on county and state, but on Dep Index is still showing NaN

Comment: Deprivation Index will be NaN  for dataM rows not have  matching country and state in dataframe dataD

Comment: Yes, and I tested this: dataM = dataM[dataM['County'] == 'Baldwin County']

Comment: To filter results with Baldwin County which is on both data frames, and it shouldn't return NaN

Comment: I already solved it going a different route. I posted why I did as an answer if you'd like to know what I did. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an inner join -

```
dataM = pd.merge(dataM, dataD[['depr_ind_col', 'County', 'State']], how='inner', left_on=['County', 'State'], right_on=['County', 'State'])
```

Comment: I already solved it going a different route. I posted why I did as an answer if you'd like to know what I did. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

After so many tries, I ended up concatenating the county and state for dataM and assigning it to a new column name "County, State". Then, I just used a simple merge method:

```
dataM = pd.merge(dataM , dataD, how='right', on=['County, State']) 
dataM = dataM[dataM['County, State'] == 'Baldwin County, GA']
dataM
```

[image]

That gave me the results a was looking for. I will split the county and state after this, and then drop rows with NaN on Births.

Thank you for your help though!